# Python: Ordering a set of string

Tags: python

I have a list: `[ "123-12 abc, qwerty", "pol, T. top", "14-89 toy, rap"]`.

I want to output it like this using Regular Expressions:

qwerty abc 123-12

T. top pol

rap toy 14-89

Is there any pythonic way to solve this? Thank you.

Comment: So, basically you want to reverse the words in a string? Why do you have to use regex for that?

Comment: First, it would help if you explained what exactly you want to do, instead of relying examples. Second, what did you attempt and why/how it did not work? Third, the title of your question is totally irrelevant to the question: you do not have a set, and you do not order it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use regular expression.Here is a simple solution

```
l = [ "123-12 abc, qwerty", "pol, T. top", "14-89 toy, rap"]
for i in l:
    t = i.split(",")
    print(t[1],t[0])
```

Comment: `123-12 abc` should be split, etc, and `T. top` shouldn't be split, so don't split on spaces.

Comment: Thank you but I have tried that.

Comment: The numbers wont flip with the word. Sorry I'm new to this website